# EXTJS Cell Edit with up and down arrow keys is incrementing and decrementing the values

Tags: javascript, extjs

in my application, when I try to edit a text box cell and press up arrow or down arrow, it is automatically incrementing or decrementing the value of the cell.

Expected behaviour: When I edit a cell and change the value and press up or down arrow it should behave as if I pressed enter and should move to a cell up or down.

Do we have any keywords with which I can debug the code and see what is making the values increment or decrement. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this updating the logic using ***beforecellkeydown*** event! Please check the below example! I hope this helps!

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 400,
            height: 200,
            title: 'Editable Grid Example',
            store: {
                fields: ['name', 'age'],
                data: [{
                    name: 'John',
                    age: 25
                }, {
                    name: 'Jane',
                    age: 30
                }, {
                    name: 'Mike',
                    age: 28
                }]
            },
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                flex: 1,
                editor: 'textfield'
            }, {
                text: 'Age',
                dataIndex: 'age',
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'numberfield',
                    keyNavEnabled: false,
                }
            }],
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'cellediting',
                clicksToEdit: 1,
                id: 'celledit'
            },
            
            listeners: {
            beforecellkeydown: function (grid, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, event, eOpts) {
                if (event.getKey() === event.UP || event.getKey() === event.DOWN) {
                    var editingPlugin = this.getPlugin('celledit');
                    if (editingPlugin.editing) {
                        event.stopEvent();
                        var targetRow = event.getKey() === event.UP ? rowIndex - 1 : rowIndex + 1;
                        if (targetRow >= 0 && targetRow < grid.getStore().getCount()) {
                            var targetCell = this.getView().getCellByPosition({
                                row: targetRow,
                                column: cellIndex
                            });
                            if (targetCell) {
                                var originalValue = record.get(this.columns[cellIndex].dataIndex);
                                var currentValue = editingPlugin.getActiveEditor().getValue();
                                if (originalValue !== currentValue) {
                                    editingPlugin.completeEdit(); // Complete the current edit
                                    editingPlugin.startEditByPosition({
                                        row: targetRow,
                                        column: cellIndex
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the working example. Its a good working example, but I don't want to do "keyNavEnabled:false" because when I change the number value in the current cell  and press up arrow, I want the cell to move up after changing the value in the current cell. Example, if I change the existing cell from 5  to 6 and press up arrow, the existing cells value should change to 6 and move the focus to the upper cell ready for editing.Thanks!

Comment: Try remove the "keyNavEnabled:false" config and check again! This will do increment/decrement based on up/down navigation key!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think my question is not clear. I don't want the increment and decrement to happen and at the same time when the value of a cell is changed and the up arrow is pressed the cursor should move to a cell above.

Comment: so you want to make the cursor to move to the cell above or below if the user has made changes to the current cell? if yes, i have updated the code..please check!

Comment: once again thanks for the quick working solution. Is the increment and decrement using an up arrow by default in extjs?